# Table with TEXT datatype in MySQL not getting copied to Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have never used mysql but in one of my recent work I have to create a table in Oracle using DB link which connects to MySQL DB.

The table I want to copy has a column with datatype as TEXT

from oracle I try to fire this command

```
create table test_table
as
select * from <MYSQL_TABLE>@DBLINK;
```

I get following error

```
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00997: ugyldig bruk av datatypen LONG
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I tried to use to_char() function while creating the table

```
create table test_table
as
select to_char(col_with_TEXT_datatype) from <MYSQL_TABLE>@DBLINK;
```

it gives following error

```
ORA-00932: inkonsekvente datatyper: forventet CHAR, fikk LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone tell me how can I create this table in Oracle.

Please note that this is not one time activity, this table creation will be part of a weekly job schedule via procedures. So this has to be achieved through create table statement only.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a view on MySQL side that only contains the data types Oracle expects and knows to handle. Then direct your copy-query to that view!

The advantage would be that the data type conversion would be done on side of MySQL.

E.g. if your table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `xy` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` long);
```

create the view like this:

```
create view xy_oracle_view as select id, t, cast(d as char(512)) from xy;
```

and reference the view in you copy statement with

```
create table test_table
as
select * from xy_oracle_view@DBLINK;
```

Watch out! If the char size that you use in the cast is greater than 512 you will get a column of type text instead of varchar anyway! (Tested on my MySQL 5.7.)

Comment: I have asked my DBA to do this, since I myself do not have access. they have used  CAST(col AS CHAR(1024)). But in view it is still appearing as TEXT. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you use a size of more than 512 characters, the column type will be a text type instead of varchar. I forgot to mention this in my answer and will add this.